# How do I specify DRF oauth required_scopes in function based api_view?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, oauth2client, django-oauth, django-oauth-toolkit

I'm trying to make my function based rest framework views which use the `@api_view` decorator with the Django OAuth Rest Framework Toolkit, where I'm using `TokenHasScope` as the permission_class. However, this needs a mandatory attribute called `required_scopes` but I'm not sure how I can get this specified in a function based views?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you asked for, but an alternative to using Viewsets could be defining a view that subclass `ScopedProtectedResourceView` and set the scopes with the `required_scopes` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a view that subclasses `TokenHasScope` then hardcode `get_scopes` method to return the scopes you want. If the scopes change across different view, you can create a decorator which takes in a list of scopes and passes it on, then set your `get_scopes` method to pick up the scopes from that decorator.